# How do I calculate solution of two differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given are two differential equations:

$\ddot{x} (t)+16x(t)=0$ and $\ddot{y}(t)+16y(t)=2sin(4t)$.

How do I calculate solution of two differential equations if the begning values are $x(0)=0$,$\dot{x}(0)=1$ and $y(0)=0$, $\dot{y}(0)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Periodic boundary conditions, a sinusoidal right-hand side for the non-homogeneous equation.  I'd say, use the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 0):

The x- and y- motions are not coupled, they are independent. We can superpose by eliminating $t$ from the two solutions obtained independently for a relation between x- and y-.